# display touch friendly menu on Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

On devices with touch input Windows 10 displays nice touch-friendly menues, so i'm looking for a way to add this into my application. Is there any new flag or a method to show such a menu without making it completely owner-draw?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The control you are referencing is a [MenuFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.aspx). Depending on whether you're using a mouse or touch, Windows 10 will automatically space the menu items closer/further to be optimal for the input you're using.

To use this control (the easy way), your app should be a Windows 10 Universal (UWP) app, which can be written in C#, VB and C++.

You can find official samples for UWP apps on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).

Comment: A downvote almost 3y after date (while the control mentioned is still the valid answer), wonderful ... :p